# Netbeans File I/O FileNotFound /FileLocation Null

Tags: java, file-io

I cant seem to get file IO to work within netbeans

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("File Location: "+ System.getProperty("myFile.txt"));

        //File file = new File("myFile.txt");

    }
```

I get an exception for this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And output:

```
File Location: null
```

without the `System.getProperty` and I get the `FileNotFoundException`

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: myFile.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

The file itself is in the source directory of the project and also shows up in the IDE under the Source Packages > myproject> myFile.txt

Any reason why its not finding the file or any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Try putting the file in the project root directory, just a level above the src directory. As a peer of src and direct child of project root

Comment: make this a solution and I will give you credit for it as the right answer

Comment: Just made it solution. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File should be placed here if you're calling it like this "myFile.txt"

```
MyProject (project root)
    myFile.txt
    src
```